# $\sin2\alpha$ in terms of $\tan\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

I am solving a geometry problem and I arrived at $$QD^2=54+36\sqrt2\sin2\alpha$$ I have previously found that $\tan\alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}$. Using $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$, we can actually find the values of $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ and then we have $$\sin2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$$ Is this necessary, though? The authors have written that $$\sin2\alpha=\dfrac{\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}$$ How can I derive that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I guess we are talking about that, yes. But I didn't make a typo, that is exactly how it is written in my book.

Comment: If $\alpha=\frac\pi4$, then $\sin2\alpha=1$ and $\frac{\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}=\frac12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real identity is

$$\sin 2\alpha = \frac{2 \tan \alpha}{1 + \tan^2 \alpha}$$

which you get by noticing that
$$\begin{align}
\sin 2\alpha &= 2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha \\
&=2\tan \alpha\cos^2\alpha \\
&=\frac{2\tan\alpha}{\sec^2\alpha} \\ &=\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I really don't know what $\sec\alpha$ is? Is there another way to derive it?

Comment: $\sec\alpha=\frac1{\cos\alpha}$

Comment: @Hipo Another way you can do it is by considering $\sin 2\alpha = \cos 2\alpha \tan 2\alpha$, where $\cos 2\alpha = \frac{1-\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}$ and  $\tan 2\alpha = \frac{2\tan \alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin 2 \alpha &=\frac{2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha}{\cos ^{2} \alpha+\sin ^{2} \alpha} \cdot \frac{\sec ^{2} \alpha}{\sec ^{2} \alpha} \\
&=\frac{2 \tan \alpha}{1+\tan^2 \alpha}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Check your algebra.

Comment: The *numerator* of the second row should be $$2\Bigg(\frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}\Bigg).$$

Comment: Middle step should read 2*sin*secant/(1 + tan^2)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Fixed.